# does e.stopPropagation() in jquery works on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want prevent eventpropogation from element inside an anchor tag i m trying to use    e.stopPropagation();  it doesn't seem to work is it possible or i m just wasting time please help me out of here
javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alink .p').click(function(e){
    alert("hi");
    e.stopPropagation();  
});
```

html is :

```
<div>
    <a href="http://google.com" class="alink" >Google links
          <p class="p">Another Links to prevent default</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

thanks for your precious time

Comment: It's `document`, not `"document"`, you have syntax error (missing `});`), and if you want to prevent link from taking you to a page use `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation()` stops passing the event to handlers further away in DOM structure from the element, on which originally event was triggered. It does not, although, prevent action that has already been triggered.

**You should use `event.preventDefault()`** to stop mentioned above default action.

**Sources:**

- [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
- [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: Ran across the same problem when working on something for an answer to another question. This kind of makes sense, but only if the "follow link" action is triggered *before* the event reaches the `<a>`. If you call `.stopPropagation()` on a child element of the `<a>` then I'd expect that action to never be triggered, because the `click` event should never be reaching the anchor.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, did you ever find a solution to this? Trying to work out the exact same thing as you.

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

> It will not stop any default behaviours (such as link clicks) and you might want to consider using [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in addition to this method.
>
> `event.stopPropagation()` is only for event handlers, not default behavior.
>
> `event.preventDefault()` If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

You had some spelling errors in your script and its `document` not `"document"`.

#### Check out the Sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/sEypD/2/)

#### Sample

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alink, .alink > .p').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery - event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
- [jQuery - event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: Generally it is not a good idea to `return false;` when you only want to prevent the default action; it will interfere with other event handlers. Also, you can only use it on the end of the function, so if there is any javascript error, the browser will still follow the link, which might be unwanted. As Esailija said, `e.preventDefault()` is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alink .p').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        alert("hi");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use- `e.preventDefault()` to stop default behavior. stopPropagation is used to stop event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed enclosing brackets here, didn't you?

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.alink .p').click(function(e){
    alert("hi");
    e.stopPropagation();  
});
```

Fix brackets and then use e.preventDefault() instead.