# Default behavior of <a> (href) inherited by its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

[Demo on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/zMPUD/)

HTML:

`<a href='http://www.jsfiddle.net'><span>link</span></a>`

Script:

```
$('span').click(function(event) {
  window.open('http://www.google.com');
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  //The line below does prevent jsfiddle.net from loading on the right.
  //event.preventDefault();
});
$('a').click(function() {
  //This function is not triggered as event propagation has been stopped.
  alert('You will never see this.');
});
```

Clicking on "link" in the demo will cause both google.com and jsfiddle.net to be opened. Here comes my question: Why is the default behavior of `<a>` (opening jsfiddle.net in this case) inherited by its children (`<span>` in this case)? Are there any specifications I can refer to? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not so much inheriting as simply being applied to all contents of it.

Comment: `<a href='http://www.jsfiddle.net'><div>link</div></a>` is invalid HTML

Comment: I think the answer is: due to the event model introduced in DOM Level 2.

Comment: @Andrew Barber Any specifications (link preferred)I can refer to, please?

Comment: @Oriol Changed `div` to `span`. Results are the same.

Comment: @zanetu No, on Firefox 27 with `<div>`, the page http://www.jsfiddle.net didn't open

Comment: @Aurelio De Rosa Could you please be more specific by providing a link or something?

Comment: @zanetu Probably you can just type "DOM Level 2" on Google? https://www.google.it/search?q=DOM%20Level%202

Comment: @Oriol All right. Should have added something like `on my browser`...

Comment: @Aurelio De Rosa I searched. But still can't find the paragraph that specifies the inheritance behavior.

Comment: You can use `return false`, http://jsfiddle.net/zMPUD/1/

Comment: It's not inheritance, it's bubbling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the default behavior of `<a>` inherited by its children?

Because it makes sense :-) Every click on a link or its descendants does trigger an event whose default action is to activate the link.

> Are there any specifications I can refer to?

Check [*Default actions and cancelable events*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow-default-cancel) in the DOM level 3 spec for an explanation of cancellation. However, DOM3 does not specify any default actions on its own.

Those are done in the HTML 5 spec, for clicks specifically in the [*Interactive Content* section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#interactive-content-0):

> When a pointing device is clicked, the user agent must run these steps:
>
> 1. [Set some flags]
> 2. Let `e` be the [nearest activatable element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#nearest-activatable-element) of the element designated by the user, if any. To obtain that, check
>      whether the target has a defined activation behavior. If it does, take
>      it, if it doesn't (and has a parent element) then **repeat the
>      checking with the *parent* element of the target**.
> 3. If there is an element `e`, run pre-click activation steps for it if any.
> 4. Dispatch the required `click` event.
> 5. If there is an element `e` and the click event is not canceled, run
>      post-click activation steps for it if any.
> 6. If there is an element `e` and the event is canceled, run canceled
>      activation steps for it if any.
> 7. [Reset flags]

The activation behaviour is defined by the elements themselves, e.g at the [`<a>` element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) to get and follow a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this answer here:

[does e.stopPropagation() in jquery works on anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952176/does-e-stoppropagation-in-jquery-works-on-anchor-tag)

You may combine with `event.preventDefault();` in order to get the desired behaviour. StopPropagation prevent events to be fired but not default behaviours such navigate to a page when clicking a `<a>` tag.

Comment: Rather than saying that it stops events from being fired it's more correct to say that it stops events from bubbling up to parent nodes. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html