# Prevent redirect when clicking on anchors child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that's located in an anchor, and that button has some logic that's triggerd by `clicking` on it.

The problem is that whenever I click on that button, the app get's redirected due the `anchor` parent element.

```
<a href="foo" id="bar">
  <span id="button">click me</span>
</a>
```

I tried using [.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) like it's mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369035/how-do-i-prevent-a-parents-onclick-event-from-firing-when-a-child-anchor-is-cli), however it doesn't work.

I tried:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfyy10a8/2/).

However, if I replace the parent `anchor` with a `div`, then it works - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1dgd9m1/1/)

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**: I know I can prevent redirecting with `e.preventDefault()`, however, I want when I click on the parent element to redirect, and when I click on the button **not** to redirect and start doing my JS functions (open modal).

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: This is a duplicate of so many questions, use the search.

Comment: @Nit yes, I seached a lot but I didn't found a solution when the parent is an `anchor` element.

Comment: What is the purpose of differentiating between clicking on the span vs clicking on the anchor tag wrapped around it?

Comment: It seems that the button click should trigger anchor `href` redirection. If you want the button to have different action then move it outside the anchor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('#bar').on('click', function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('#button') ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //your logic for the button comes here
    }
    //Everything else within the ancho will cause redirection***
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="foo" id="bar">OK
  <span id="button">click me</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Clicking on the text `OK` is doing a post back

Comment: Good! That's how it's supposed to work. The question is only concerned, if I understood it correctly, with not redirecting when the button is clicked. And I added **OK** to show that anything else in there will redirect when clicked.

Comment: @PeterKA that's is. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfyy10a8/3/

Comment: stopPropagation stops events from bubbling up, in this case you still clicked on the link since it wraps the span so you need to stop the browser from doing its default action.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `e.preventDefault();` on links:

```
$('#bar').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can also add it on your example, all together:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `e.preventDefault()` instead:

```
$('#button').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

See [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8952209/5230059) for why `e.stopPropagation()` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

use `return false`:

```
$('#button').on('click', function (e) {

    //some logic
    $(this).css('color', 'red');

    return false;
});
```

The reason why stopPropagation wont work is because it will prevent event handlers from running, not native behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has an answer but however, I made mine work by   `returning false on the "onclick" attribute of the child element`.

```
<a href="https://google.com">
    <button onclick="return doTask()">Do not navigate</button>
</a>

function doTask(){
  //... write action

  return false; <- This prevents the click action from bubbling up to parent tag
}
```