# Prevent route change in Vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

```
<router-link to="SOME_ROUTE">
    <div class="outer-div">
        <div class="inner-div" v-on:click="doSomething"></div>
    </div>
</router-link>
```

Some I am trying to create a link which will have a image in it. I am trying to make the inner div to do something without triggering the route change, how am I be able to achieve this? I have tried the event modified `v-on:click.stop`, but it doesn't seem to work, the route will still change after the `.inner-div` is clicked. Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: How does the rendered dom look like?

Comment: something like `<a href="SOME_ROUTE"><div class="outer-div"><div class="inner-div"></div></div></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to use

```
<div class="inner-div" v-on:click.prevent="doSomething"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="inner-div" v-on:click.stop="doSomething"></div>
```

to prevent the default action. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8952200/6279569
Here's the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/yjq7hntf/).

Comment: Great! That' exactly what I wanted! Thanks!